# Determine which fields to look for(select2) in a specific django field admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, jquery-select2

I have this model

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nurse = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
   ....
```

in django admin I define search and autocomplete fields:

```
search_fields = (
        'patient__first_name', 'patient__last_name',
        'doctor__first_name', 'doctor__last_name', 'nurse__first_name',
        'nurse__last_name', 
    )

    autocomplete_fields = ['patient', 'doctor', 'nurse']
```

I have tried to do this:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'patient':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Profile.objects.filter(role=PATIENT)
    if db_field.name == 'doctor':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Profile.objects.filter(role=DOCTOR)
    if db_field.name == 'nurse':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Profile.objects.filter(role=NURSE)

    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

But it doesn't work with select2 widget, that applies when i want to add search. **Is there a way to filter queryset to a certain field?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any solve of this problem by native in django. I used [dal](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) select2 form. I define [Select2QuerySetView](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#dal_select2.views.Select2QuerySetView) for every Profile field and filter queryset in it + filter by search.